IntegerQ and testing for a positive integer
One can solve Linear, Constant-Coefficient Difference Equations (LCCDEs) using the ZTransform.  Recall that LCCDEs have integer arguments and can be illustrated such as:
f[n+2] = 3 f[n+1] + 2 f[n]
and some initial conditions, such as f[0] = 1 and f[1] = 1.
(The Fibonacci series is defined in just this way, just with the constants 3 and 2, above, replaced by 1.)
We can of course write code to compute f[n] for a general n by:
f[0] = 0;
f[1] = 1;
f[n_Integer] := 3 f[n-1] + 2 f[n-2]

However, this is slow for large n and doesn't reveal mathematical structure.
Another approach is to use ZTransforms.  We take the ZTransform of the equation defining f[n], solve for the ZTransform of f, then compute the InverseZTransform to recover a mathematical form for f[n].  So in the above case:
myZTrans = ZTransform[f[n + 2] == 3 f[n + 1] + 2 f[n], n, z];

myZSol = Solve[myZTrans /. {f[0] -> 0, f[1] -> 1}, ZTransform[f[n], n, z]];

myFinalEq = InverseZTransform[(ZTransform[f[n], n, z] /. First[myZSol]), z, n]

$$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(3+\sqrt{17}\right)\right)^n-\left(\frac{1}{2}
   \left(3-\sqrt{17}\right)\right)^n}{\sqrt{17}}$$
It is pretty surprising that this solution always yields an integer.
For example:
myFinalEq /. n -> 100 //Simplify

3537646303459605111696665428274832196761996930395731479
IntegerQ[%]

(* True *)
But the final solution gives an integer for ALL n in the PositiveIntegers.
I'd like to compute that result.
Here is an attempt that does NOT work:
Assuming[n \[Element] PositiveIntegers,
 IntegerQ[myFinalEq ]]

(* False *)
I've tried Simplify[], FullSimplify[], and other obvious approaches, but have never computed True.
Is there a way to compute that myFinalEq yields an integer for all integers n > 0?

fyi, IntegerQ checks literally that head of expression  is Integer. So this will not work. For example t=myFinalEq/.n->1 and now IntegerQ[t] gives False. Even though Simplify[t] gives 1. Because the Head of t is Times.  I tried Reduce but it did not work. So would need something more advanced I think to proof it by Mathematica.

eqns /. f -> Function[{n}, Evaluate@myFinalEq] // FullSimplify verifies that the solution is valid for all n. Since the given recurrence equations can only generate integers for positive integer n, then the result is integer for positive integer n

@DavidG.Stork You could use binomial formula to prove myFinalEq is an integer!

@UlrichNeumann:  Really?  How?  And would it work for the infinite number of other such problem cases?

@DavidG.Stork I don't know the infinite number of other cases. But for your case we get an expression which only contains even powers of Sqrt[17]

@UlrichNeumann:  Please SHOW what you mean, not merely REFER to what you believe.  Thanks.

Off-topic: a fast way to compute terms is RecurrenceTable[{f[n+2] == 3*f[n+1]+2*f[n], f[0] == 1, f[1] == 1}, f[n], {n, 0, 20}] and an easy way to find your Z transform solution is RSolve[{f[n+2] == 3*f[n+1]+2*f[n], f[0] == 1, f[1] == 1}, f[n], n].

There is nothing surprising if one knows binomial formula.

From number theory, we know the expression is a rational number and the numerator is an algebraic integer. Further, the numerator, being a difference of powers, is seen to be divisible by $\sqrt{17}$. Therefore the expression is a rational algebraic integer; in other words, an integer in the school-math sense.

So how do you show/implement that in Mathematica?

@DavidG.Stork Your query to Michael E2's comment  seems to be much more polite than the form "Please SHOW what you mean, not merely REFER to what you believe."

At this point I don't know, or I would post an answer. I just thought that the math might help someone with the Mathematica.

Would this count?: FindLinearRecurrence[Table[(-(1/2 (3 - Sqrt[17]))^n + (1/2 (3 + Sqrt[17]))^n)/Sqrt[17], {n, 0, 10}]] (different idea than the alg. num. thy. of my previous comment).

too long for a comment:
In my comment a only gave a solution idea, which I describe here in more detail!
With binomial formula

myFinalEq is transformed to

The sum only has non zero elements if k is odd. It follows

Because EvenQ[k-1] the expression Sqrt[17] ^(k - 1) gives an integer.

Your argument is incomplete. From the last line it still can be rational.

@yarchik I only tried to show that the expression is rational, not more.

I personally like this argument (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3470563/435814), but I do not know how to express it in MA

@yarchik Thanks for this interesting link!

Define:
a = 1/2  (3 + Sqrt[17]);
b = 1/2  (3 - Sqrt[17]);
f[n_]:= (a^n - b^n)/Sqrt[17]
{a*b, a + b}  // Simplify
(* {-2, 3} *)

With this
$$
f_n=\frac{a^n-b^n}{\sqrt{17}}.
$$
Let us prove that $f_n$ is integer by mathematical induction.

Check the base cases, i.e., whether $f_n$ is integer for $n=0$ and $1$:
IntegerQ[f[0]]
IntegerQ[f[1] // Simplify]
(* True *)
(* True *)


Check the induction step, i.e., whether $f_{n+1}$ is an integer if $f_{n}$ and $f_{n-1}$ are integers. MA needs a hint about the values of the sum and product of $a$ and $b$ as derived above. Explicit forms of $a$ and $b$ are not needed.
Clear[a, b]
Simplify[f[n+1] == 3 f[n] + 2 f[n-1], Assumptions -> {a*b == -2, a + b == 3}]
(* True *)



$f_{n+1}$  is an integer when the right-hand side (RHS) is an integer. In turn, the RHS is an integer per the induction hypothesis.
My solution is not fully satisfactory because the induction relation is specified explicitly. Without knowing the recursion relation, it is hard to relate $f_{n+1}$ to the previous values of the sequence automatically. A fully automatic proof should not rely on this hint. Rather, one should provide the assumptions $f_{n-1}, f_n\in \mathbb{Z}, ab=-2, a+b=3$, and MA should verify that $f_{n+1}\in \mathbb{Z}$.

This is efficient:
m = {{3, 2}, {1, 0}};
f[0] := 0
f[n_?(# > 0 &)] := Nest[m . # &, {1, 0}, n - 1][[1]]

The recursive matrix multiplication of integer entry matrix yields integers and eigensystem confirms formula.
You can derive formula and check f[100] yields result:
{e, v} = {DiagonalMatrix[#1], Transpose[#2]} & @@ Eigensystem[m];
p = First[v . MatrixPower[e, n - 1] . Inverse[v] . {1, 0}] // 
  FullSimplify
f[100]



Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question.

Sorry for misunderstanding
